# Optirun glxgears: Cannot access secondary GPU - error: [XORG] (EE) No devices detected

Tags: graphics, dell, nvidia-optimus

I have problem with optirun command on Ubuntu 12.10 installed on notebook DELL M6600. In the BIOS I have enabled Optimus technology. I have two graphics:

```
lspci -vnn | grep '\''[030[02]\]'
```

- Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0126] (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
- NVIDIA Corporation GF104 [Quadro 4000M] [10de:0e3b] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])

I have installed nvidia drivers:

```
dpkg -l | grep nvidia

ii  boinc-nvidia-cuda                         7.0.27+dfsg-5ubuntu0.12.04.1               amd64        metapackage for CUDA-savvy BOINC client and manager
ii  bumblebee-nvidia                          3.0.1-3~quantalppa2                        amd64        nVidia Optimus support using the proprietary NVIDIA driver
ii  nvidia-common                             1:0.2.71.1                                 amd64        transitional package for ubuntu-drivers-common
ii  nvidia-cuda-doc                           4.2.9-1ubuntu1                             all          NVIDIA CUDA and OpenCL documentation
ii  nvidia-cuda-gdb                           4.2.9-1ubuntu1                             amd64        NVIDIA CUDA GDB
rc  nvidia-current                            304.64-0ubuntu1~quantal~xup1               amd64        NVIDIA binary Xorg driver, kernel module and VDPAU library
ii  nvidia-experimental-310                   310.14-0ubuntu1                            amd64        Experimental NVIDIA binary Xorg driver, kernel module and VDPAU library
rc  nvidia-settings                           304.64-0ubuntu1~quantal~xup1               amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
rc  nvidia-settings-experimental-310          310.14-0ubuntu1                            amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
ii  nvidia-settings-updates                   304.51-0ubuntu2                            amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
```

When I try this:

```
 optirun -vv -debug glxspheres
```

I got:

```
[  912.342326] [DEBUG]Reading file: /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf
[  912.497379] [DEBUG]optirun version 3.0.1 starting...
[  912.497472] [DEBUG]Active configuration:
[  912.497560] [DEBUG] bumblebeed config file: /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf
[  912.497600] [DEBUG] X display: ebug
[  912.497660] [DEBUG] LD_LIBRARY_PATH: 
[  912.497694] [DEBUG] Socket path: /var/run/bumblebee.socket
[  912.497724] [DEBUG] VGL Compression: proxy
[  912.734313] [INFO]Response: No - error: [XORG] (EE) No devices detected.

[  912.734376] [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: [XORG] (EE) No devices detected.

[  912.734399] [DEBUG]Socket closed.
[  912.734447] [ERROR]Aborting because fallback start is disabled.
[  912.734477] [DEBUG]Killing all remaining processes.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I got the same problem. When I intalled bumblebee, it did not recognise my discreet card. Looking for this problem, I found that Ubuntu uses the key nvidia instead of nvidia-current to refer to the drivers of nVidia.

So try this:

Make a backup of the file /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf

- `sudo cp /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf.backup`

(for example)

Edit that file (use the editor you want, for example gedit):

- `sudo gedit /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf`

Go down to the section `[driver-nvidia]`.

There, change the value of

- `KernelDriver=nvidia-current`

to

- `KernelDriver=nvidia`

and

- `Module=nvidia-current`

to

- `Module=nvidia`

Save the file and reboot.

Now try again:

- `optirun -vv -debug glxspheres`

If you get your same error, restore the configuration file:

- `sudo cp /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf.backup /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf`

Have Luck.

Comment: I can confirm, that this worked for me - after the primusrun had seemingly spontaneously ceased to work.

Answer (score 0):

One time I had the exact same problem, IIRC I didn't have bbswitch installed. Do you have it? If not, install, reboot and try again.
If you have suspended your notebook, I also had problems with using optirun after suspending/hibernating, try rebooting the machine.

Comment: When I try to install bbswitch, DELL not boot properly. I can't reach login sreen. I am very confused. I had to renstall 'bumblebee' to get to previous state.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this problem was adding my card into `/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia` configuration file.

Uncomment the line:

```
BusID "PCI:01:00:0"
```