# Bumblebee: Cannot access secondary GPU - error: [XORG] (EE) No devices detected

Tags: 13.04, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

After upgrading to 13.04, I get this error and other answers ([Optirun glxgears: Cannot access secondary GPU - error: [XORG] (EE) No devices detected](https://askubuntu.com/questions/249038/optirun-glxgears-cannot-access-secondary-gpu-error-xorg-ee-no-devices-de), ['Cannot access secondary GPU' error with Bumblebee](https://askubuntu.com/questions/165347/cannot-access-secondary-gpu-error-with-bumblebee)) didn't help.

```
dpkg -l | grep nvidia

ii  bumblebee-nvidia                              3.2.1-1~raringppa2                          amd64        NVIDIA Optimus support using the proprietary NVIDIA driver
ii  nvidia-310                                    310.44-0ubuntu2                             amd64        NVIDIA binary Xorg driver, kernel module and VDPAU library
ii  nvidia-settings-310                           310.44-0ubuntu1                             amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
```

This is my `/etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf`: 
http://pastebin.com/G9R55VMr

This is `/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia`: http://pastebin.com/9xNUPp6b

This is `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`: http://pastebin.com/tCnSCz0B

This is `/etc/modprobe.d/bumblebee.conf`: http://pastebin.com/WtX1LR9d

This is `/etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-310_hybrid.conf`: http://pastebin.com/CbVg2FN1

My `/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.d` folder contains only `10-dummy.conf` file, that is empty.

This is `/var/log/Xorg.8.log`: http://pastebin.com/iSMXT7aE

This is `optirun -vvv glxspheres` output: http://pastebin.com/rbyUhRNr

Ask for further details, if needed!

Comment: output of optirun -vvv glxspheres  ??

Comment: DO you have a `/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.d/` directory? Please post the contents of the files in that directory as well as `/var/log/Xorg.8.log`.

Comment: Edited with both requests! Thank you for your help!

Comment: how did you install bumblebee ?

Comment: sudo apt-get install bumblebee virtualgl linux-headers-generic

Comment: @Qasim: all three packages are installed from official repos. Please, don't be obvious and read carefully pasted bin contents.

Comment: just asking .... i have checked every file you have pasted and compared with mine ....they are all same....

Comment: This [askubuntu answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/368139/21679) helped me.

Comment: This helped me. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the following file:

```
/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-nvidia-current-latitude-e6530.conf
```

I deleted it and **optirun** worked!

Answer (score 18):

The following AskUbuntu answer fixed it for me:
https://askubuntu.com/a/285638/47280

Basically, you need to edit `/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia` and uncomment the following line:

```
BusID "PCI:01:00:0"
```

In the config, it states that this is necessary for Ubuntu 13.04. This number refers to the BusID of your GPU, so if it's different then go to the other answer for full instructions.

Comment: Anyone using a Lenovo ThinkPad T420 will need this answer!

Answer (score 4):

In `/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia` , uncomment

```
BusID "PCI:01:00:0"
```

and replace with

```
BusID "PCI:0x:00.0"
```

where x is the number that you see in 'lspci' list next to 3D controller, which should be your nvidia card

Comment: ... and this worked?

Comment: yes and no - it fixed problem with non existed secondary GPU, but did not make a solution (work is unstable and has issues with sleep mode)

Comment: @MaximSinev Did you fix the sleep error?

Answer (score 1):

Well I had same problem after upgrade and nothing I found helped. I had newest version (3.2.1) installed, because I re-added ppa after upgrade and updated bumblebee.

I did one stupid thing though: I removed ppa with ppa-purge and removed bumblebee. Then I added ppa and installed bumblebee again. And magically it started working (at least after reboot). I can't really tell you why though...