# Cannot access secondary GPU running Bumblebee

Tags: nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

I'm trying to get Bumblebee working again after an upgrade to Saucy.

Running software with Optirun gives the following output:

```
optirun nvidia-settings
[   45.697126] [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: [XORG] (EE) Failed to load /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libglamoregl.so: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libglamoregl.so: undefined symbol: _glapi_tls_Context
[   45.697179] [ERROR]Aborting because fallback start is disabled.
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks! :)

Answer (score 5):

### Only for ubuntu 13.10

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-319-updates nvidia-settings-319-updates
```

Then you need to edit /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf

```
KernelDriver=nvidia_319_updates
LibraryPath=/usr/lib/nvidia-319-updates:/usr/lib32/nvidia-319-updates
XorgModulePath=/usr/lib/nvidia-319-updates/xorg,/usr/lib/xorg/modules
Driver=nvidia
```

Restart bumblebee

```
sudo service bumblebeed restart
```

Now try :

```
optirun /usr/bin/<app>
```

Comment: This worked for me using Vervet. I only changed nvidia-319-updates to nvidia-340-updates.

Answer (score 2):

**Fix by purging and re-installing**

I could not figure out the particular problem, but I was able to recover by purging all of the packages associated with bumblebee (I used the "Complete Removal" tag in Synaptic, which I believe is equivalent to the "purge" command in apt-get). I removed all packages matching `bumblebee`, `nvidia`, `primus`, and one called `bbswitch-dkms`. I re-installed bumblebee, bumblebee-nvidia, and mesa-tools. At that point, I could run `optirun glxgears` and `primus glxgears`.

I still find that other applications --- Cool VL Viewer and Imprudence --- which ran under optirun before my upgrade to Saucy now crash. Cool VL Viewer runs without optirun.

**Also fix some library path problems**

Cool VL Viewer and Imprudence required libraries i965.so and swrast.so, which were not on the paths that they searched.

I worked around the problem, without understanding the root of it, by entering two symbolic links:

> /usr/lib64/dri -> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri
>
> /usr/lib32/dri -> /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri

I'm not sure whether to regard this as a Bumblebee problem, but the fact that Cool VL viewer worked *without* optirun, then failed *with* optirun, and the fact that the unfound libraries appear to relate to Intel graphics rather than Nvidia, suggest that the redirection of Intel calls is failing under some circumstances.

Comment: This doesn't fix for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same issue - seems to be related to [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/glamor-egl/+bug/1232658) Fix provided there failed to solve this problem for me and it looks like we have to wait for a better release of it. Somebody have alredy mentioned there that the fix does not work.