# Bumblebee 16.04: nvidia-375 depends on xserver-xorg-legacy

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, dependencies, bumblebee

I updated my packages today, and now I believe I am having this issue: [Bumblebee: [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: [XORG] (EE)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/863696/bumblebee-errorcannot-access-secondary-gpu-error-xorg-ee)

The recommended solution is to uninstall xserver-xorg-legacy. However, nvidia-375 now appears to depend on xserver-xorg-legacy.

I want to continue using bumblebee because I want to be able to activate and deactivate my discrete graphics card without restarting, and continue using the GUI even if something goes wrong with the NVIDIA driver.

Is there a way to get nvidia-375 to work with bumblebee, or will I have to go to an older version of the nvidia driver?

**EDIT:** I found what appears to be a solution

Answer (score 1):

These instructions appear to be accurate: http://www.webupd8.org/2016/08/how-to-install-and-configure-bumblebee.html

In my case, because I already had a mostly-working setup, I did this:

### My Solution

1. Add the bumblebee/testing PPA

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/testing
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
2. Use Synaptic to update Bumblebee, keeping my existing /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf
3. Add the following lines to /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf

   ```
   # Xorg binary to run
   XorgBinary=/usr/lib/xorg/Xorg
   ```

   Right after the lines

   ```
   # Directory with a dummy config file to pass as a -configdir to secondary X
   XorgConfDir=/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.d
   ```

   Then save and close
4. Restart the computer, just in case
5. Make sure everything is actually working by using

   ```
   optirun glxinfo
   ```

   And seeing that it outputs something different from before, even when used twice in a row

---

### Notes

The conclusion of this bug report was what led me to the conclusion that this was the correct solution for now: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=815888

The PPA has this rather intimidating warning label:

> Unless you're a developer, it's unlikely that you want to use this PPA. Use ppa:bumblebee/stable if you're just a regular user.
>
> Things may break your system in this PPA.

However, there appears to be no Xenial (16.04) in bumblebee/stable, so that isn't an option.

Answer (score 0):

As you said in your own answer you can add the testing ppa.
The second way is to simply remove xserver-xorg-legacy and use the stable ppa:

First remove the xserver-xorg-legacy without touching depending packages:

```
sudo dpkg -r --force-depends xserver-xorg-legacy
```

Allright - Bumblebee is working again. But apt will give you errors because of missing dependencies.
This can be fixed by creating a dummy-package for xserver-xorg-legacy using equivs.
First we create a config file using equivs-control:

```
equivs-control xserver-xorg-legacy
```

This will create the config file for the new package in the current directory.
You can use nano to edit this one:

```
nano xserver-xorg-legacy
```

The content of the file should look like this:

```
    ### Commented entries have reasonable defaults.
### Uncomment to edit them.
# Source: <source package name; defaults to package name>
Section: misc
Priority: optional
# Homepage: <enter URL here; no default>
Standards-Version: 3.9.2

Package: xserver-xorg-legacy
Version: 2:1.18.4-1ubuntu0.2 
# Maintainer: Your Name <yourname@example.com>
# Pre-Depends: <comma-separated list of packages>
# Depends: <comma-separated list of packages>
# Recommends: <comma-separated list of packages>
# Suggests: <comma-separated list of packages>
# Provides: <comma-separated list of packages>
# Replaces: <comma-separated list of packages>
# Architecture: all
# Multi-Arch: <one of: foreign|same|allowed>
# Copyright: <copyright file; defaults to GPL2>
# Changelog: <changelog file; defaults to a generic changelog>
# Readme: <README.Debian file; defaults to a generic one>
# Extra-Files: <comma-separated list of additional files for the doc directory>
# Files: <pair of space-separated paths; First is file to include, second is destination>
#  <more pairs, if there's more than one file to include. Notice the starting space>
Description: Dummy package for nvidia-375.66 update 
 This Package does nothing... it just exists...
```

Important at this point is the Package name:

```
Package: xserver-xorg-legacy
```

And that you have to stage the version
so 2:1.18.4-**0**ubuntu0.2 
becomes 2:1.18.4-**1**ubuntu0.2

If you're done with your config you have to create the package from your config:

```
equivs-build xserver-xorg-legacy
```

This will create a package file with the given name and the version.
In my case this was xserver-xorg-legacy_1.18.4-1ubuntu0.2_all.deb

Okay, let's install it using dpkg:

```
sudo dpkg -i xserver-xorg-legacy_1.18.4-1ubuntu0.2_all.deb
```

Thats it...

xserver-xorg-legacy doesn't do something anymore and apt is happy with no missing dependencies.

Good Luck ;-)